# dynamicly(fluid) spaced multiline elements (like justified)

Tags: css, layout

I would like to achieve this:

[image]

These are just any elements inside a container which has a fluid dynamic width.
I would like to keep N items in a single row with dynamic spacing between them, so
my layout will always have 4 in a row and also be responsive.

The trick is **not using** any wrapping elements per-row, just minimum DOM with whatever CSS.

[**Live Playground**](http://jsbin.com/irijuz/1/edit)

Comment: try to see ths article: http://barrel2013.staging.barrelclient.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan - his solution requires that I know how many elements I have

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use % widths and margin.

Something like this (taken from your example):

```
ul{ list-style:none; }

li{ 
  float: left;
  display:block;
  width:21.7%; 
  height:50px; 
  background:red; 
  margin: 0 4.4% 4.4% 0;
}
li.z{
  margin-right: 0;
}

li:nth-child(2n){ 
  background:blue; 
}
```

Note, I added a "z" class to your last element, i.e. every 4th.

HTH.

Comment: doesn't work with percentages...please use the playground to prove your theories

Comment: That is the live version of it, I updated it a little, hopefully this is what you want.  Let me know if it isn't and I'll see if I can help you further.

Comment: You can't have fixed size element widths with responsive. If you have a static width, then just change the "width" to whatever width you need.  It sounds like you just need a % based margin right.

Comment: no I don't want any margins set..at all..see like my demo here: http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/tFwxu

Comment: Ok, I think your best bet is to use media queries to adjust your css according to the view ports you need to support for your responsive site.  Here are the standard ones from css-tricks:  http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: ok I mean, not responsive like what you think, I mean..fluid. I don't want media queries, I want it to be completely fluid. I think it might be possible with flex-box magic somehow..

Answer (score 0):

Make the function fire on load and on resize.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/j8PKn/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    ul {
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    min-width:400px;
}
ul li {
    width:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background:#ff0000;
}
ul li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background:#0096ff;
}
```

JS:

```
var organize = function(){
    // get the outer width
    shWidth = $('ul').width();
    console.log(shWidth);
    // generate the width of each column
    colWidth = shWidth/4;
    console.log(colWidth);
    // add the correct margin to the first column
    $col1 = $('ul li:nth-child(4n+1)');
    $col1.css({'margin':'10px ' + (colWidth - 50) +'px 10px 0'});
    // add the correct margin to the center columns
    $colCenter = $('ul li:nth-child(4n+2), ul li:nth-child(4n+3)');
    $colCenter.css({'margin':'10px ' + (colWidth - 50)/2 +'px'});
    // add the correct margin to the 4th columns
    $col4 = $('ul li:nth-child(4n+4)');
    $col4.css({'margin':'10px 0 10px ' + (colWidth - 50) +'px'});
}


organize();
```

Comment: you used containers for each element..I prefer not..just to work with the elements themselves

Comment: I just read your other comments. What you want is not achievable with no other html markup or margins.