# justified all images in div without any space

Tags: html, css

How to justify all images inside a div so that there is no any space left in the left-side and the right-side of the div.

Here is my HTML:

```
        <ul class="thumnails">
            <li class="img-thum">
                <img src="broward.jpg"/>
                <p class="thum-capt">How a Squad of Ex-Cops Fights Police Abuses</p>
            </li>

            <li class="img-thum">
                <img src="honey.jpg"/>
                <p class="thum-capt">The Men's Rights Movement and the Women Who Love It</p>
            </li>

            <li class="img-thum">
                <img src="bottles.jpg"/>
                <p class="thum-capt">Bottled Water Comes From the Most Drought-Ridden Places in the Country</p>
            </li>

            <li class="img-thum">
                <img src="snyder.jpg"/>
                <p class="thum-capt">6 Dumb Things Dan Snyder Has Said About the Name of His Football Team</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And here my CSS

If I am setting the padding-right with value, then there will be a space in the right-side.

```
.thumnails {
width: 100%;
display: block;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0; 
margin: 12px auto;  
position: relative;
list-style: none;
}

.thumnails .img-thum {
width: 23%;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0; 
padding-right: 1.5%;
margin: 0 auto; 
}

.thumnails .img-thum img {
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.thumnails .img-thum .thum-capt {
width: 100%;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: serif;
}
```

---

---

**[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/94pd50aL/)**

Comment: Please make jsfiddle.

Comment: can you give me a link of some "sample images" for doing that in jsfiddle?

Comment: Use Lorempixel.com for images

Comment: I put the fiddle in the question. Please have a look on that.

Comment: **Duplicate** - http://stackoverflow.com/q/17301161/104380

Comment: @vsync are you sure the question is same? it even doesn't solve my problem there.

Comment: why isn't it the same? it looks the same to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read this article by Chris Coyer:

http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/

Your css should be like this:

```
.thumnails {
width: 100%;
display: block;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0; 
margin: 12px auto;  
position: relative;
list-style: none;

text-align: justify; /* <== add this */
}

.thumnails .img-thum {
width: 23%;
display: inline-block; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}


.thumnails .img-thum img {
display: inline-block; /* <== and this */

width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.thumnails .img-thum .thum-capt {
width: 100%;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
position: relative;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: serif;
}


/*and this*/
.thumnails:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%; /* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

please see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t8k2k3rL/)

Comment: What I've made now can be a solution

Comment: Thanks! That's what I really want. Thanks for understanding my question!

Comment: I still don't understand what do you mean or the function of "Ensure there are at least 2 lines of text...." can you explain it so that I understand it, please...

Comment: We have applied a `text-align: justify;` to `.thumnails`, this usualy work on text with multiple lines (text with just one line are not justified). We've add a dummy line using `.thumnails:after` so we can use the trick

Answer (score 0):

try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/94pd50aL/1/)**

Just update this css to solve this problem.

CSS:

```
.thumnails .img-thum {
    width: 23%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;     
    margin: 0;  
    float:left;
}
```

Updated fiddle **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/94pd50aL/4/)**

Space between images: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/94pd50aL/5/)**. Hope you need like this

Comment: Still there is a space left in the right-side of the wrapper. What I want is all the content inside the black-background-wrapper is justified so that there is no space in the right-side and in the left-side anymore.

Comment: updated my code.. just increase width to 25% to get expected output

Comment: I want there is a margin for each images so that they are not stucked together.

Comment: That almost work, but that so complicated. Ghilas answered it corectlly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Solved Your Problem >> [**Images Without Space and justified in middle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/nxwzhofs/4/)

Test in Full Screen >> [**FullScreen Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/nxwzhofs/4/embedded/result/)

[image]

**Modified css**

---

```
.thumnails {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin:1%;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    white-space:no-wrap;
}
.thumnails .img-thum {
    width: 22.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumnails .img-thum img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.thumnails .img-thum .thum-capt {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: serif;
}
```

Comment: I want there is a margin for each images so that they are not stucked together, but it is justified in the wrapper so that there is no space in the left side and in the right side of its wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure proper sizing it's nearly always worth using `box-sizing:border-box` so that padding and borders are **included** in width calculations.

Then the are two simple methods (based on your current code) although there are other options available.

[**JSfiddle (Inline-block)**](http://jsfiddle.net/94pd50aL/3/)

[**Jsfiddle (Floats)**](http://jsfiddle.net/94pd50aL/2/)

**CSS re Inline Block**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.thumnails {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 12px auto;  
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    background:black;
    font-size:0; /* required to remove white space */
}

.thumnails .img-thum {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block; /* change to float:left for float version */
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.thumnails .img-thum img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.thumnails .img-thum .thum-capt {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: serif;
```

}

Comment: I want there is a margin for each images so that they are not stucked together.